# undo feature branch merge

Tags: git, merge

I've been working on a new feature on a branch for the last while. When the feature was finished, I squash-merged the feature branch back to master, and deleted the feature branch. The hash of the merge commit is 7ba3dc2fea43cd33c4d5ba11baf2765cbbdb0284.

I now need to revert this merge. Specifically, what I want to achieve is:

1. the changes for the new feature are removed from master
2. the changes for the new feature are on a feature branch which could subsequently be merged to master

Some additional information which may be relevant:

- there have been a few commits to master subsequent to the merge commit, but it doesn't matter if undoing the merge loses these commits, because the changes are trivial to re-apply
- I don't have the ability to commit directly to master, so the process of undoing the merge will have to be achieved by creating branches, raising a PR, then merging the branch to master once the PR has been approved.

How can I move the changes for the new feature back to a feature branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For once, the fact that you used a squash merge rather than a true merge is going to make your life easier. (I'm assuming that by "squash-merge", you mean [the `--squash` argument to `git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---squash), or equivalent functionality in other UIs.)

A "squash merge" doesn't actually reference the original commits in any way, it just creates a new commit which applies all the changes they would have brought in. So to undo that commit, you can create a new branch from master, and use [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) to create a new commit that undoes all the changes from the squash merge commit.

To get the old branch back, you need to find the commit hash it was pointing at when you deleted it. If you used a "Pull Request" or "Merge Request" in a web UI (Github / Gitlab / BitBucket), it will be listed there (and might even have a "restore branch" link). If you had it checked out locally, it will probably be visible in `git reflog`. Once you've found it, just type `git branch feature-foo-resurrected abc123def`, replacing "abc123def" with the commit hash you've found.

As a last resort, you could create a branch based on the squash commit, by using [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to create a new commit with the same content. (Just pointing a branch at that commit won't help, because that's already in the history of "master", so will show as "nothing to merge".)

So the whole sequence might look like:

```sh
git switch master
git pull --ff-only origin

# create a branch which undoes the squash merge
git switch -c revert-feature-foo
git revert 7ba3dc2fea
git push origin

# now create a branch which *redoes* the squash merge on top of that
# only needed if you can't find the original feature branch
git switch -c feature-foo-resurrected
git cherry-pick 7ba3dc2fea
git push origin
```

Comment: Question - shouldn't the revert be with the option `-m 1` since that is a merge commit you're reverting?

Comment: @mnestorov No, because a "squash merge" isn't really a merge; it only has one parent.

Comment: I understood it as he squashed the feature branch, produced a single commit of the feature branch and merged that into master, thus producing a merge commit.

Comment: @mnestorov It's possible, but "squash-merge" would normally refer to [the `--squash` argument to `git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---squash) or equivalent functionality in other UIs. I'll update to make it clear that I'm assuming that.

Comment: @IMSoP your interpretation of "squash merge" is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach

**Revert a commit**

```
$ git revert --no-commit '<commitnumber>'
# Files that were modified in the commit will be changed in your working directory
$ git commit -a -m "Revert commit <commit number>"
```

**Create a feature branch and cherry pick commit**

```
$ git checkout -b 'Feature Branch name'
$ git cherry-pick '<commitnumber>'
$ git commit
```

Most of the time you would end up with some conflicts based on the number files which have been changed in the git repo in subsequent commits